# DateTime parsing of weeks for '30 Dec 2013' is incorrect

Tags: ruby, date, datetime

`DateTime#parse` on `'Mon, 30 Dec 2013 00:00:00 UTC +00:00'` is wrong for the week. I chose ISO 8601 week-based year and week number `%V` (week number `01..53` of the week-based year).

With format `"%V-%y"`:

```
DateTime.parse('Mon, 30 Dec 2013 00:00:00 UTC +00:00').strftime "%V-%y"
#⇒ "01-13"

DateTime.parse('Mon, 30 Dec 2013 00:00:00 UTC +00:00').strftime "%W-%y"
#⇒ "52-13"

Date.strptime('01-13', '%V-%y')
#⇒ Tue, 01 Jan 2013

Date.strptime('52-13', '%V-%y')
#⇒ Tue, 01 Jan 2013
```

`Mon, 30 Dec 2013 00:00:00 UTC +00:00` is not `"01-13"`.

But if I use `"%W"` format, the result is correct (`"52-13"`).

What is it? Or did I make some mistakes?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong except your claim that something is wrong. What is wrong?

Comment: @sawa this is unfair, the question is clearly stated and `30-Dec-13` does definitely not belong to the _first_ week of _2013_ (first LOC.)

Comment: @mudasobwa That is right. `30-Dec-13` is in the first week of ISO 8601 year, and is in the conventional year 2013, but is not in the first week of the conventional year 2013. But that has nothing to do with the OP's claim that the parsing is wrong. The parsing is actually not wrong. But I think you understand what is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With week-based week number (`%V`) one should use week-based year (`%g`):

```
DateTime.parse('Mon, 30 Dec 2013 00:00:00 UTC +00:00').strftime "%V-%g"
#⇒ "01-14"
```

Answer (score 0):

The **cday, cweek and cyear** are the methods based on the **commercial dates**.

**commercial: Creates a date object denoting the given week date.**

So, the last days of an year can be the same week to the new year's starting days.
 For example 2013 december last dates and 2014 Jan starting days are of the same week, so the week number of the date **'Mon, 30 Dec 2013 00:00:00 UTC +00:00' comes to the new week of next year** after all the weeks of the year are completed.

So,

```
"Mon, 30 Dec 2013 00:00:00 UTC +00:00".to_date.cweek ==> 1
"Mon, 30 Dec 2013 00:00:00 UTC +00:00".to_date.cwday ==>1 (1st week day of week 1 2014(but date is still of  2013)
"Mon, 30 Dec 2013 00:00:00 UTC +00:00".to_date.cwyear ==> 2014
```

Those are commercial dates, Now check,

```
"Mon, 30 Dec 2013 00:00:00 UTC +00:00".to_date.year ==> 2013
```

This is Normal year.

[This has a perfect example](http://apidock.com/ruby/Date/commercial/class)